# How to click on a button among elements with the same class names but different parent class names in puppeteer js?

Tags: puppeteer

```
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="insider">
      <button class="mybutton">No1</button> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
   <div class="insider">
      <button class="mybutton">No2</button> 
   </div>
</div>
```

As it can be seen in the code above, I have 2 buttons with exact same `class` names but different parent names.

I am able to select the right one but upon returning the `class` name to use in `page.click()` I obviously receive the `class` name which is not what I am looking for to click.

given the number of divs could be random and without paying attention to the order, how can I `page.click` on 2nd one lets say in this context or if there are more divs the one I am looking for?

My code so far :

```
  const selectedElement = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const arr = querySelector('.parent2').querySelector('button').className
    return arr
  })
  await page.click(`.${selectedElement }`);
```

Which obviously `selectedElement` receives `mybutton` as the `class` name and clicks the first one on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)   between the ancestor and the descendant selectors. Note: it's not neccessary to give the intermediate selector like: `.parent2 .insider .mybutton`, it is enough to give the outsides: `.parent2 .mybutton`.

Then you can grab the element as an [`ElemntHandle`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.0&show=api-class-elementhandle) and click it.

**For Example:**

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('.parent2 .mybutton')
await elementHandle.click()
```

Or you can use the stricter [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` by giving the path from ancestor to descendant:

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('.parent2 > .insider > .mybutton')
await elementHandle.click()
```

---

Did you know? If you right click on an element in Chrome DevTools "Elements" tab and you select "Copy": there you are able to copy the exact selector or xpath of an element. After that you can switch to the "Console" tab and with the Chrome api you are able to test the selector's content, so you can prepare it for your puppeteer script. E.g.: `$('.parent2 > .insider > .mybutton').innerText` should show the button text that you expected to click on, otherwise you need to change on the access, or you need to check if there are more elments with the same selector etc. This may helps to find more appropriate selectors.